# Android Settings app preference files

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've read Android's [settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) tutorial, and want to use the new "headers" feature in order to accomplish something like the left image. To be exact, I want to have a global "enabled" checkbox, and below it some preference headers surrounded with a category header.

[image]

Can I make it be just by using XMLs ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by writing your own adapter class that handles headers. I found this nice  pretty straightforward  [example](http://xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article4/master-on-off-preferences-with-ice-cream-sandwich#c1352542579-1) for native settings looking like preference.

It's working on handset but it's not fixed for tablet (app crashes as it tries to use two-pane layout).